# Rearrange equation to solve for a different variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking at VBA code (function) written by someone else.

Here is the code:

```
Function EuropeanDelta(StrikePrice, MarketPrice, Volatility, InterestRate As Double, PC As String, ValueDate, ExpiryDate As Date, Optional PriceOrYield As String = "P") As Double

Rem Declare our working variables
  Dim r As Double
  Dim d1 As Double
  Dim d2 As Double
  Dim t As Double
  Dim SqT As Double
Rem End of variable declaration

  If PriceOrYield = "Y" Then
    MarketPrice = 100 - MarketPrice
    StrikePrice = 100 - StrikePrice
    If PC = "C" Then
      PC = "P"
    Else
      PC = "C"
    End If
  End If

Rem Initiase our working variables

  t = (ExpiryDate - ValueDate) / 365
  SqT = Sqr(t)
  r = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(1 + InterestRate)

  d1 = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(MarketPrice / StrikePrice) + (Volatility * Volatility * 0.5) * t) / (Volatility * SqT)

Rem Quick logic to deal with Calls or Puts

  If PC = "C" Then
    EuropeanDelta = Exp(-r * t) * Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(d1)
  Else
    EuropeanDelta = -Exp(-r * t) * Application.WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(-d1)
  End If

  If PriceOrYield = "Y" Then
    EuropeanDelta = EuropeanDelta * -1
  End If

End Function
```

The whole problem is based around the line for "d1". I would like to re-organise to solve for "StrikePrice". I have tried writing it out mathematically and then re-arranging, then swapping back to VBA.

Comment: `StrikePrice  = MarketPrice / Application.WorksheetFunction.exp(d1 * (Volatility * SqT) / t) - (Volatility * Volatility * 0.5)`

Comment: BTW You can replace `Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln()` with `Log()` as they are the same function and it is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

This is just algebra - high school math.

Take it in steps.  Make sure you do the same operation to both sides to make sure that equality still holds.

Here's your starting equation:

```
d = {ln(m/s) + v*v*t/2}/(v*sqrt(t))
```

Multiply both sides by the denominator of the RHS:

```
d*v*sqrt(t) = ln(m/s) + v*v*t/2
```

Subtract `v*v*t/2` from both sides:

```
(d*v*sqrt(t) - v*v*t/2) = ln(m/s)
```

Apply the exponential function to both sides, noting that `exp(ln(x)) = x`:

```
exp(d*v*sqrt(t) - v*v*t/2) = m/s
```

Multiply both sides by s:

```
s*exp(d*v*sqrt(t) - v*v*t/2) = m
```

Divide both sides by `exp(d*v*sqrt(t) - v*v*t/2)` to get the desired result:

```
s = m/exp(d*v*sqrt(t) - v*v*t/2)
```

Let's see if this function makes sense.

At `t = 0` the denominator `exp(0) = 1`, so the strike price is equal to the market price.

As `t -> infinity`, we hope that the denominator gets large so `s -> zero`.  L'Hospital's Rule will help here.

Comment: Thank you vm for this response and the explanation. The only question I have is the starting formula you used looks slightly different than I expected. 

d = {ln(m/s) + v*v*t/2}/(v*t*t)

I see the v*v*t/2 part as (v*v*0.5)*t ?

And the Sqt variable isnt there anymore? I know its basic but I need to get this right

Comment: "I" need to get this right?  I'm the one who's done the work so far.  I'll be happy to redo as long as you make your formula clearer.  Does Sqr(t) mean "square root of t" to you?  Poor names for variables and functions on your part.

Answer (score 1):

@duffymo is correct, but am giving the answer directly in terms of VBA code

```
' d1 = (Log(MarketPrice / StrikePrice) + (Volatility * Volatility * 0.5) * t) / (Volatility * Sqr(t))
'
' Volatility * Sqr(t) * d1 = Log(MarketPrice / StrikePrice) + Volatility^2 * t/2
'
' Log(MarketPrice / StrikePrice) = Volatility * Sqr(t) * d1 - Volatility^2 * t/2
'
' MarketPrice / StrikePrice = Exp(Volatility * Sqr(t) * d1 - Volatility^2 * t/2)
'
StrikePrice = MarketPrice / Exp(Volatility * Sqr(t) * d1 - Volatility^2 * t/2)
```

---

*Other Notes :*

- For brevity replace `Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln()` with `Log()`
- There is no need cache `SqT = Sqr(t)` since it is only used once.
- For clarity replace `Volatility*Volatility` with `Volatility^2` as internally it does the same thing.